# Windows Phone crackle sound when `SoundEffectInstance.Stop()`

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, audio, xna

I have few `SoundEffectInstance`. There is сrackle sound when I stop it (I need to do it fast as possible). I readed somewhere that its "sound effect"  coused by cutting of sound wave. I tried to write something like

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate        {
        for (float i = 1f; i > 0.01; i /= 2f)
        {
            foreach (var sound in Sounds.Values)
            {
                if (sound != null && !sound.IsDisposed)
                {
                    sound.Volume = i;
                }
            }
            Thread.SpinWait(500); //Tried different dellays here
        }
    });
    Sounds.Clear();
```

but it didn't realy help. What can I do to avoid сrackle on fast sound stop?

Comment: The next sample after a stop must have a value that's reasonably close to the previous one.  If it is not then you get a "step", it generates lots of high-frequency noise that sounds like a crackle or tick.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt mind this.